# what's the rank of $ I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

$X$ is $n \times (k+1)$, and $X^TX$ is invertible. So what's the rank of $ I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, which $I$ is diagonal standard matrix.

Comment: at least $n-k-1$

Comment: Yes, it is right. I have a question whether $r(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) = r(X^TX)$, can you explain it in detail? Very appreciate.

Comment: open a new question, with your thoughts and attemps on the problem

Comment: If you are allowed to use the SVD of $X$, it is often a simple way to prove this kind of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $P$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto a subspace, then $I - P$ is the matrix of the projection onto the orthogonal complement of this subspace.